# How to continue job even when script fails

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a job in my pipeline that has a script with two very important steps:

- `mvn test` to run JUnit tests against my code
- `junit2html` to convert the XML result of the tests to a HTML format (only possible way to see the results as my pipelines aren't done through MRs) that is uploaded to GitLab as an artifact
- `docker rm` to destroy a container created earlier in the pipeline

My problem is that when my tests fail, the script stops immediately at `mvn test`, so the `junit2html` step is never reached, meaning the test results are never uploaded in the event of failure, and `docker rm` is never executed either, so the container remains and messes up subsequent pipelines as a result.

What I want is to be able to **keep a job going till the end** even if the script fails at some point. Basically, the job should still count as failed in GitLab CI / CD, but its entire script should be executed. How can I configure this?

Comment: Check also GitLab 13.8 (Jan. 2021) and [exit codes with allow-failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65860343/6309).

Comment: Have you ever tried "set +e"? It will not fail the job when a command exit code is other than 0. You could check the exit code to do some specific thing, or just ignore it.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In each step that you need to continue even if the step fails, you can add a flag to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in that step. For example:

```
...
Unit Tests:
  stage: tests
  only:
    - branches
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - ...
```

It's that `allow_failure: true` flag that will continue the pipeline even if that specific step fails. Gitlab CI Documentation about allow_failure is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure

Update from comments:
If you need the step to keep going after a failure, and be aware that something failed, this has worked well for me:

```
./script_that_fails.sh || FAILED=true

if [ $FAILED ]
    then ./do_something.sh
fi
```

Comment: `allow_failure` works to keep the pipeline going but it doesn't prevent the job from ending prematurely. I did fix my issue by using the `before_script` and `after_script` variables, though, since they're executed regardless of whether the job fails or succeeds. So you did set me on the right path.

Comment: Ah, ok. I misunderstood then. For those cases where you need to know that something failed, but need it to keep going, I've done something like `./script_that_fails.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 || FAILED=true`, then if you need to do anything if it fails, you can `if [ $FAILED ]; then ./do_something.sh; fi` type of thing. That's what I've done in the past.

Comment: @Adam had same issue and your comment tip about `./script_that_fails.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 || FAILED=true` helped me a lot. I think that should be the correct answer to this question

Comment: Similarly, if you don't care to know if something failed, you could just do `./script_that_fails.sh || true`. This will allow your CI/CD to continue past `./script_that_fails` but it will stop if it encounters any further errors. I feel like this is much safer than setting `allow_failure : true` for **all** commands.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but too late to edit my previous post. [Here is the recommendation from GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#ignore-non-zero-exit-codes):
`./script_that_fails.sh || exit_code=$?`

Comment: if you need multiple commands and do something if at least one fails, you can also start with `exit_code=0` then do one or more `./script_that_fails.sh || ((exit_code|=$?))` this way exit_code will remain at 0 if all succeeds