# how to continue running scripts if one of them fails? GITLAB CI

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

here is my yml file:

```
stages:
  - testing
  - deploy 

docker_job:
  stage: testing
  tags:
    - docker
  image: atools/chrome-headless:java11-node14-latest 
  
  before_script:
    - npm ci 
    - npx playwright install 
    - npm install allure-commandline --save-dev
  
  script:
    - npm run BookingTestDEV --project=BookingTesting
    - npx playwright test --project=BookEngineTests
    - npm run BookingTestNEO --project=BookingTesting


  after_script:
    - npx allure generate allure-results --clean 
  rules:
      - when: always
  allow_failure: true
  artifacts: 
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./allure-report
    expire_in: 7 day 

pages: 
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir public 
    - mv ./allure-report/* public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - when: always
```

if first script
- npm run BookingTestDEV --project=BookingTesting fails, other will be skipped, how to run them anyway ? is there any analog of if(): always like on github ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitLab CI: How to continue job even when script fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180675/gitlab-ci-how-to-continue-job-even-when-script-fails)

Comment: @jormaster3k i have tried allow_failure and you can see it on my code also, but it doesnt work the way I expect it to work, scripts are skipped anyway

Comment: @Vladeezy That is because adding `allow_failure` prevents a failing job from failing the rest of the pipeline. Normally when a job fails, the pipeline fails. Adding `allow_failure` will make sure that the specific job can fail but the pipeline will continue.

Comment: @seldesjo got it, so allow_failure will not help me in my situation those || thats what I need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases, the pipeline should fail if one of the commands throws an exit code that is not 0. However, in some cases, the rest of the commands should run anyway. A possible solution for this would be to add  `|| true` at the end of the command.

For example:

```yaml
 script:
    - npm run BookingTestDEV --project=BookingTesting || true
    - npx playwright test --project=BookEngineTests
    - npm run BookingTestNEO --project=BookingTesting
```